# get string/character representation of rpart regression tree

Tags: r, r-caret, rpart

I am using code like this:

```
library(datasets)
library(rpart)
library(caret)

options(warn=-1)
set.seed(42)


x <- subset(iris, select=-c(Species, Sepal.Length))

fitControl <- trainControl(
     method = "repeatedcv"
     , number = 10
     , repeats = 10
 )

fit_data <- caret::train(
     x = x
     , y = iris$Sepal.Length
     , method = 'rpart'
     , trControl = fitControl
     #, control=rpart.control(minsplit=3, minbucket=1, cp=0.001)
     #, metric = "ROC"
     #, tuneLength = 20
    , control = rpart.control(maxdepth = 3) #  minbucket=20
)

model <- fit_data$finalModel
model
```

The last line:

```
model
```

prints the model as string/character on the screen:

```
n= 150 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 150 102.1683000 5.843333  
  2) Petal.Length< 4.25 73  13.1391800 5.179452 *
  3) Petal.Length>=4.25 77  26.3527300 6.472727  
    6) Petal.Length< 6.05 68  13.4923500 6.326471 *
    7) Petal.Length>=6.05 9   0.4155556 7.577778 *
```

Is there a way to get the actual string/character representation explicitly? I tried something like this:

```
 df <- data.frame(test = as.character(model))
```

to write the model as string into a dataframe. It prints too much ...

Comment: The model doesn't run. Well it does with errors, could you please provide a reproducible example?!

Comment: I am using the iris set - very reproducible IMHO ...

Comment: Please run it and see what it produces. Remove the warning part first.

Comment: I am sorry I just did and it works fine - what is your error message?

Comment: Just NAs: `Error: Stopping
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)` Anyways, what exactly do you want to see on the screen?

Comment: I am pretty sure someone with your reputation gets a simple regression tree using iris to work? Well, it works for me sorry ...

Comment: Alright, what is your expected output?

Comment: Not sure but here is something that looks like what I think you need: `res <-quote(knn$finalModel);
eval(res)`. `knn` because I ran a knn locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
model_text <- capture.output(print(model))
OutputDataSet <- data.frame(model_text = model_text, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure about the expected output but we can save the model as a character as follows:

```
model <- quote(fit_data$finalModel)
```

We can then simply call it whenever needed as follows:

```
eval(model)
```

Comment: thanks this is actually better than my answer and work in sql server. thanks!

Comment: I am sorry this does not appear to work. eval still results in an object of type rpart. basically I want to execute something like toString() on this object if that makes sense?

Comment: btw toString(model) does not produce expected results - see adapted question.

Comment: Is this what you need? `get(toString(quote(model)),envir = .GlobalEnv)` or just `get("model",envir = .GlobalEnv)` ?. I find the use of strings kinda inefficient. This requires knowing the environment which again is inefficient.

Comment: thanks - i still end up with the object rather than the string printed on the 'screen'

Comment: capture.output(model) seems to almost do the job. issue it captures it line by line rather than one string blob

Comment: Do you just want the output as "model" or something else? Not sure exactly what you mean by print on screen.

Comment: I want to capture what the code line model prints on the screen. In other words the string.

Comment: What do you intend to do with it? Seems like `dput` would do the job? You say  capture.output **issue it captures it line by line rather than one string blob**

Comment: simple append as a row of a column to a dataframe - it is a trick to get  the model as string back from a stored procedure